# C#, MVC, PUT returns 405 Method Not Aloowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httprequest, put

I am trying to send PUT request but it always return 405 error. I have spent all night trying to fix it, I think I did all the combinations of the settings in web.config, tried to modify the code in with different approaches and I feel helpless at this point. Maybe I miss something else. I'm rather fresh in mvc. I'm using the same approach for the GET and it works fine.

Here is js code:

```
    var msg = {
        name: newName,
        description: newDesc
    };

    var stringMSG = JSON.stringify(msg);
    console.log(stringMSG);
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: '@Url.Action("PutSite", "Home")',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            id: id,
            json: stringMSG
        }
    }).done(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

C# Controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage PutSite(string id, string json)
    {
        return ApiProvider.UpdateSite(GetSessionId(), id, json);
    }
```

C# classes:

```
    public static HttpResponseMessage UpdateSite(string sessionID, string siteID, string json)
    {
        var client = GetHttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, $"{ApiBaseUrl}/api/session?id={sessionId}/site/{siteID}")
        {
            Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.Default, "application/json")
        };

        return PutResponse(client, request);
    }

    private static HttpResponseMessage PutResponse(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var response = client.PutAsync(request.RequestUri,request.Content).Result;
        return response;
    }

    private static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return client;
    }
```

And web.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <webServices>
        <protocols>
          <add name="HttpGet" />
          <add name="HttpPost" />
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Accept, expiry, uid, access-token, token-type" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44345" />
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I want to make an update so I use PUT

Comment: Perhaps you're missing `[HttpPut]`?

Comment: as it is `MVC` you need to add `HttpPut` attribute to your action

Comment: I have tried that already. Same result

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. My attempt: 1) Create a new ASP.NET (Framework 4.7.2) MVC application 2) Replace my web.config with yours. 3) Delete the script rendering in the views that the new web.config broke. 4). Add a `[HttpPut] public HttpResponseMessage Test(string id, string json)` method. 5) Run it and submit a post - the method is hit, and the expected 201 method (I returned `Created`) is received in Postman.

Comment: The only issue i noticed was with your use of `string json` rather than an actual model (so it's `null`).

Comment: @John you are the best man. I have spent all night on it. The issue was not the implementation but that my client has changed something in the api and the sessionID caused the error. The json was not null but it had wrong formatting like this "{\"name\":\" New Site 1\",\"description\":\"undefined\"}" . Anyway I know the problem now, thanks! :)